# Предлагаю объединить метки “наречия” и “наречие”

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено

Предлагаю объединить метки “наречия” и “наречие”. Мне кажется, мы отдаем предпочтение множественному числу. Тогда пусть метка “наречия” будет главной, а “наречие” – синонимом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метки объединил, синонимы создал. Спасибо!